# git push delete verify oldvalue

Tags: git

When deleting Git ref locally, I may verify that the ref points to the proper value `<oldvalue>` (i.e. no other local process has changed it):

```
git update-ref -d refs/myrefs/tag1 <oldvalue>
```

However, when deleting a ref on a remote server, then [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) cannot verify that the ref points to a certain object:

```
git push -d origin refs/myrefs/tag1
```

So, it cannot verify other client has not changed the remote ref. I know I can do `git ls-remote origin refs/myrefs/tag1` and then `git push -d`. However, is there any atomic, (or almost atomic), one request, way how to delete Git remote ref if it equals to `<oldvalue>` only?

Comment: Haven't actually tried this, but `--delete --force-with-lease` probably *ought* to do the trick. Test it out (build a case that should fail, see if it fails) and if it doesn't work as desired, perhaps that will be considered a bug in Git to be fixed in the next release...

Comment: @torek Thanks, `git push --force-with-lease=refs/myrefs/tag1=<oldvalue> -d refs/myrefs/tag1` is working as desired. Make an answer from your comment and I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `--force-with-lease` does internally, so the trick is to hook it up externally, and [per your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74402763/git-push-delete-verify-oldvalue?noredirect=1#comment131454437_74402763), you can run:

```
git push --force-with-lease=refs/myrefs/tag1=<oldvalue> -d refs/myrefs/tag1
```

should (and does) do the trick.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that the general form is `--force-with-lease=<name>=<value>`, where *`name`* is any valid ref and *`value`* is any hash ID.  This operation sends an update-ref operation from the local Git software to the remote Git software, much like `git update-ref` but across the Internet.  The usual `git push --force-with-lease`, without the `=<name>=<value>` part, tells Git to look up the remote's version of the upstream of a local branch name locally, and then look up that local upstream's value to get the value.  The *`name`* comes from the target of the push.

The reason for the odd construction of the sentences above is that local branch `bra` typically has, e.g., `bra` as its upstream, so that we'd be sending `--force-with-lease=refs/heads/bra=refs/remotes/origin/bra`.  However, the upstream of a branch named `bra` might be set, locally, to `refs/remotes/xyzzy/strangename` even though on remote `xyzzy`, the name of the branch is actually `br2`.  In this case the `--force-with-lease` is shorthand for `--force-with-lease=<name>=refs/remotes/xyzzy/strangename`.  That is, to get *`oldvalue`*, we look up `refs/remotes/xyzzy/strangename` locally.  Then we send an update request to remote `xyzzy` asking them to update their branch, based on the final argument to the `git push`; that's also the source for the *`name`*.  So we write:

```
git push --force-with-lease xyzzy bra:br2
```

(as we must since we want them to update their `br2`, not their `bra`), and `--force-with-lease` sends the update-ref request to *them* as "I expect `refs/heads/br2` to have OID *`old-oid`* and if it does you should set it to *`new-oid`*", where *`old-oid`* is from our `refs/remotes/xyzzy/strangename` and *`new-oid`* is from our `bra`.